# Running thread at very low priority

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, scheduler

I have created a thread in my Linux application, using pthread_create(). I would like to let this thread run at very very low priority as there are some real time threads running in the same application. The following is the code I have in the thread function itself:

```
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
        pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

        /* Trying to set lowest priority possible for this thread */
        param.sched_priority = 0;
        ret = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_IDLE, &param);
        if (!ret)
                printf("Successfully set sched policy of thread\n");
```

I want to confirm if the above code is okay or not. Does it guarantee that my thread will not be given higher priority when compared to the other real time threads. Please suggest if any changes are required. FYI, the code runs on an embedded platform.

Comment: "*Does it guarantee that my thread will not be given higher priority when compared to the other real time threads.*" so you do not want to have this low prio thread be run at all?

Comment: Ofcourse I want it to be run

Comment: Your program's threads are not the only threads that will be running on a Linux host. If you want a thread in your program to have a higher priority relative to _all_ of the threads that might be running on the platform, then you will have to boost its priority. It won't be enough to just lower the priorities of the few threads that your program controls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have used Default Linux time-sharing scheduling. as you have added  **param.sched_priority = 0;**

for that, you can check [Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html)

which states that

> ```
>    SCHED_OTHER can be used at only static priority 0 (i.e., threads
>    under real-time policies always have priority over SCHED_OTHER pro‐
>    cesses).  SCHED_OTHER is the standard Linux time-sharing scheduler
>    that is intended for all threads that do not require the special
>    real-time mechanisms.
> ```

```
   The thread to run is chosen from the static priority 0 list based on
   a dynamic priority that is determined only inside this list.  The
   dynamic priority is based on the nice value (see below) and is
   increased for each time quantum the thread is ready to run, but
   denied to run by the scheduler.  This ensures fair progress among all
   SCHED_OTHER threads.
```

Comment: I want to use SCHED_IDLE  Setting priority=0 does it conflict i.e by setting both SCHED_IDLE and priority=0 I am eventually giving this process a higher priority?

Answer (score 0):

From manual page of [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

> int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t ***attr**,
>                             void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);

you can create your own attribute and set its properties, including **priority** as you did.

```
param.sched_priority = 0;
```

And from the manual page of [pthread_setschedparam](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_setschedparam.html)

> int **pthread_setschedparam**(pthread_t thread, int policy,
>       const struct **sched_param** *param);
>
> The `pthread_getschedparam()` and `pthread_setschedparam()` allow the
>   **scheduling policy and scheduling parameters of individual threads within a multi-threaded process to be retrieved and set**. For
>   **SCHED_FIFO** and **SCHED_RR**, the only required member of the **sched_param** structure is the priority **sched_priority**. For **SCHED_OTHER**, the affected scheduling parameters are **implementation-dependent**.
>
> If the `pthread_setschedparam()` function fails, no scheduling
>   parameters will be changed for the target thread.

So above it clearly stated that you can set & retrieve the scheduling parameters for `RR` and `FIFO` scheduling policy. Also in case of `SCHED_OTHER` its implementation-dependent.

After running the thread which changes the priority, do run the command and check. For e.g run the below command

```
ps -T -l [PID]
```

and check the `priority` with respect to  `PID`.

Also read @paxdiablo answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998974/linux-threads-and-process-scheduling-priorities) about linux threads scheduling priorities.